# Fazer um sub domínio ou criar uma sub-pasta?

Tags: segurança, http, subdomínio

Hoje um vendedor de certificado *SSL* me informou que meu `site.com.br/intranet` não é seguro, que o correto seria fazer `intranet.site.com.br` isso é verdade?

Faz mesmo alguma diferença um sub-domínio em vez de de uma sub-pasta?

Comment: Depende, se o seu site só precisa acessar alguma subpasta (ou se alguns usuários deveriam ficar limitados a ter acesso só a essa subpasta), subdomínios ajudam a fazer esse controle melhor do que subpastas, mas isso tudo depende do que você está querendo implementar...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não necessariamente, me parece um pouco exagero dele (e até falta de conhecimento, ou confusão dele).

### O que é inseguro

Se a `site.com.br/intranet` página contem cookies de sessão (ou outro método de sessão) estes dados podem ser passados para o `site.com.br`, porém é totalmente possível prevenir isto, por exemplo com PHP é possível definir o PATH do cookie de sessão.

### Porque usar um sub-dominio

O sub-domínio não compartilha os cookies do site principal e isto teoricamente tornaria mais seguro.

Como eu disse não é totalmente certo e nem totalmente errado, varia de como o seu sistema foi criado usar uma sub-pasta não torna realmente inseguro.

> Claro que ele pode ter falado de outra coisa que eu realmente desconheço

Answer (score 6):

Em alguns contextos sim. Você pode, por exemplo, restringir um cookie a `pt.stackoverflow.com`; aí ele não vai aparecer se o usuário acessar `stackoverflow.com`, o que nesse caso obviamente não faz diferença, mas impede que as suas credenciais da intranet vazem para o site aberto ao público.

Outra situação na qual o subdomínio faz diferença é pra AJAX: a menos que você autorize explicitamente, o browser não vai deixar você fazer um pedido de `intranet.site.com.br` pra `site.com.br` ou vice-versa; isso protege o vazamento acidental de informações da sua intranet para o público.

(Ambos os casos de uso acima são mais relevantes quando você é um site tipo Tumblr ou GitHub, nos quais um usuário pode colocar qualquer conteúdo no subdomínio dele — no caso do GitHub, no `github.io` — mas nunca custa colocar uma camada extra de proteção no seu serviço.)